# Grouping json object in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am inserting into postgres with select. Basically converting to json type.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ON (name, number)
  JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(name, JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(phone_number_of, number))
FROM table1 t1, tale2 t2, table3 t3
WHERE
  t1.customer_fk_id = t2.id
AND t1.id = t3.proposal_customer_id
ORDER BY name, number, priority DESC
```

I am getting the output:

```
{"ALIP KUMAR" : {"Mobile" : "8*******"}}
{"ALIP KUMAR" : {"Residence" : "9******"}}
{"Abdul Gaffar" : {"Office" : "9*******"}}
{"Abdul Khalique" : {"Mobile" : "98*****"}}
{"Abdul Khalique" : {"Mobile" : "97*****"}}
```

Is there any way to group the data so one name has one key containing all the keys ie mobile, residence etc...
and if there are multiple numbers for say residence then it is put in a list.
The output  should be

```
{"ALIP KUMAR" : {"Mobile" : "8*******"}
                 "Residence" : "9******"}}
{"Abdul Gaffar" : {"Office" : "9*******"}}
{"Abdul Khalique" : {"Mobile" : ["98*****", "97*****]}}
```

Comment: Your desired result is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aggregate functions that should do what you desire with exception of storing numbers not as array if it would have only one element.

First you need to aggregate numbers with: `json_agg(number)`, grouping by `name, phone_number_of`

Then if you need to have single phone numbers as number/string instead of array then check for length using `json_array_length(json)` and if it is less than 2 then grab first element with `json->>0` and use that instead of array.

Once you have `name, phone_number_of, number_array_or_value` then group them by `name` and aggregate using function `json_object_agg(key, value)`

Those aggregate function are described here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html

Example:

```
select json_object_agg(name, phones)
  from (
        select name,
               json_object_agg(typ, case when json_array_length(numbers) < 2 then numbers->0 else numbers end) as phones
          from (
                select name, typ, json_agg(number) as numbers
                  from (
                        select 'name1' as name, 'work' as typ, '34636432' as number
                        union all
                        select 'name1' as name, 'mobile' as typ, '12453435' as number
                        union all
                        select 'name1' as name, 'mobile' as typ, '654745' as number
                        union all
                        select 'name2' as name, 'home' as typ, '8643534434' as number
                        union all
                        select 'name3' as name, 'work' as typ, '24778457' as number
                       ) AS sub1
                 group by name, typ
               ) AS sub2
         group by name
      ) as sub3
 group by name;

                             json_object_agg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 { "name2" : { "home" : "8643534434" } }
 { "name3" : { "work" : "24778457" } }
 { "name1" : { "work" : "34636432", "mobile" : ["12453435", "654745"] } }
(3 rows)
```